# How to create a folder in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Now in my code one folder is createed like `private/119` when I logged into my application. The code is,

```
if (!is_dir('private/'.$q->row()->userId)) {
    $oldmask = umask(0);
    $q=mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId,0777,true);
    umask($oldmask);
    copy('public/images/default_user.png','private/'.$q->row()->userId.'/default-profile_pic.png');
}
```

Now I want to create a one more folder inside that userId(119) folder. How to do that? I have tried something like that `$q=mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId .'/beforeconvert',0777,true);` but it is not working.

Or is the following code is correct?

```
if (!is_dir('private/'.$q->row()->userId) && !is_dir('private/'.$q->row()->userId .'/beforeconvert')) {
    $oldmask = umask(0);
    $q=mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId,0777,true);
    $create_folder = mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId .'/beforeconvert',0777,TRUE);
    umask($oldmask);
    copy('public/images/default_user.png','private/'.$q->row()->userId.'/default-profile_pic.png');
}
```

Comment: Please expand on _"it is not working"_. What happens? Any error messages? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: edit `$q=mkdir` to `mkdir`

Comment: "it is not working" means folder is not created .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code direcoty `beforeconvert` will not created if parent directory : `$q->row()->userId` already exist.

Also you don't need to create first parent directory then child. You can directly create child directory with `mkdir` it will create parent directory also.

Change your code as below:

```
<?php
if (!is_dir('private/'.$q->row()->userId .'/beforeconvert')) {
    $oldmask = umask(0);    
    $create_folder = mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId .'/beforeconvert',0777,TRUE);
    umask($oldmask);
    copy('public/images/default_user.png','private/'.$q->row()->userId.'/default-profile_pic.png');
}
```